# Camel Routes started but not run when using Camel Cache

Tags: java, maven, caching, apache-camel

I am trying to make use of Camel Cache for the first time. So I have created a small app based on camel-java maven archetype. 
My code is based on the examples from [here](http://camel.apache.org/cache.html). Here is the snippet

```
public class AddingToCache extends RouteBuilder {
   public void configure() {
            from("direct:start")
            .log("START")
            .setHeader(CacheConstants.CACHE_OPERATION, constant(CacheConstants.CACHE_OPERATION_ADD))
            .setHeader(CacheConstants.CACHE_KEY, constant("Custom_key"))
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    exchange.getOut().setBody("My custom out");
                }
            })
            .log("starting ...")
            .to("cache://cache1")
            .to("direct:next");
    }
}
```

```
public class ReadingFromCache extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:next")
            .setHeader(CacheConstants.CACHE_OPERATION, constant(CacheConstants.CACHE_OPERATION_GET))
            .setHeader(CacheConstants.CACHE_KEY, constant("Custom_key"))
            .to("cache://cache1")
            .choice()
           .when(header(CacheConstants.CACHE_ELEMENT_WAS_FOUND).isNotNull())
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        Object body = exchange.getIn().getBody();
                        System.out.println("Cache body - " + body);
                    }
                })
            .otherwise()
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        Object body = exchange.getIn().getBody();
                        System.out.println("Cache body when not found - " + body);
                    }
                })
            .end()
            .to("direct:finish");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your routes are likely running, you just haven't invoked them yet (from the code you posted above anyways).  you need to send a message to the `direct:start` or `direct:next` routes using a ProducerTemplate to exercise the routes...

> ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
>   template.sendBody("direct:start", "message");